# How to assert that currency value displayed as string has been correctly updated

Tags: c#, xamarin, ui-testing

I have string values returned in my automation test before and after the values have been changed (before = "£0 of £650", after = "£0.95 of £650"). The test I have makes a payment to an account and then goes back to check that the values have been modified correctly.

How can I check that the value of the string has been increase 0.95?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int originalIndex = currentValue.IndexOf(" ");
int newIndex = newValue.IndexOf(" ");

currentValue = currentValue.Substring(0, originalIndex);
newValue = newValue.Substring(0, newIndex);

double origCash = double.Parse(currentValue, NumberStyles.Currency);
double newCash = double.Parse(newValue, NumberStyles.Currency);
Assert.IsTrue(newCash == origCash+valueAdded);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex pattern to match the values of your string, such as

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"£([0-9\.]+) of £([0-9\.]+)"); // pseudo code
```

and then do this for before and after, extract the matches, parse to decimal and then compare...

Comment: Thanks Andreas but I only wanted to verify that the first monetary value was update so ended up going with the answer below